Add flexible space (\vfill?) above frame title in Metropolis Beamer
I like slides with little content, see below, but I would like the empty space being part above the frame title so that frame contents and frame title are not so far away from each other, essentially adding \vfill above the frame title. Can I achieve this in Metropolis? If not possible in Metropolis, I would also be interested in solutions in other styles.

The "problem file"
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[progressbar=frametitle,
subsectionpage=progressbar,
block=fill]{metropolis}
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=normal text.fg, bg=normal text.bg}
\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
  \end{frame}
\end{document}


Please add a short, but compilable test file which allows us to reproduce the problem. It should include a class, the necessary packages and a document environment.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz you should recommend the moloch style ;-)

It is a question, there is no "problem file"

@UlrikeFischer of course :)

You could add vertical fill to the frametitle template:
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme[
  progressbar=frametitle,
  subsectionpage=progressbar,
  block=fill
]{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=normal text.fg, bg=normal text.bg}
\addtobeamertemplate{frametitle}{\vfill}{}

\begin{document}
  \begin{frame}
  \frametitle{First Frame}
    Hello, world!
    \vfill
  \end{frame}
\end{document}



I agree that having the example with a light title to copy for others might be nice, I'll check if I can reproduce that
